# Testing private method using power mock which return list of Integers

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I have a private method which take a list of integer value returns me a list of integer value. How can i use power mock to test it. I am new to powermock.Can i do the test with easy mock..? how..

Comment: I think you would get more help if you gave a specific example of what you tried and what's not working.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation), in the section called "Common - Bypass encapsulation":

> Use Whitebox.invokeMethod(..) to invoke a private method of an
>   instance or class.

You can also find examples in the same section.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 12):

Here is a full example how to do to it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

class TestClass {
    private List<Integer> methodCall(int num) {
        System.out.println("Call methodCall num: " + num);
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            result.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
}

 @Test
 public void testPrivateMethodCall() throws Exception {
     int n = 10;
     List result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(new TestClass(), "methodCall", n);
     Assert.assertEquals(n, result.size());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(myClassToBeTestedInstance, "theMethodToTest", expectedFooValue);
```

Comment: I found that the class instance needs to be used rather than the class object.
(i.e. myClassToBeTestedInstance instead of ClassToBeTested.class)

Comment: is it expectedFooValue or it is parameters for theMethodToTest?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to test a private method with Powermockito and this private method has syntax:

```
private int/void testmeMethod(CustomClass[] params){
....
}
```

in your testing class method:

CustomClass[]  params= new CustomClass[] {...}
WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(spy,"testmeMethod",params)

will not work because of params. you get an error message that testmeMethod with that arguments doesn't exist
Look here:

WhiteboxImpl class

```
public static synchronized <T> T invokeMethod(Object tested, String methodToExecute, Object... arguments)
            throws Exception {
        return (T) doInvokeMethod(tested, null, methodToExecute, arguments);
    }
```

For arguments of type Array,  PowerMock is messed up.  So modify this in your test method to:

```
WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(spy,"testmeMethod",(Object) params)
```

You don't have this problem for parameterless private methods. As I can remember it works for parameters of type Primitve type and wrapper class.

"Understanding TDD is understanding Software Engineering"