# Why getDeclaredMethod doesn't work with arguments which are in relation instanceof with specific method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I have Interface:

```
public interface Car{
    public void drive();
}
```

Class which implements Car:

```
public class SuperCar implements Car{
    @Override
    public void drive(){

    }
}
```

And Class which uses Car as a method argument

```
public class CarDealer{
    public void sellCar( Car car)
}
```

I wan't to invoke *sellCar* method using *getDeclaredMethod* with *SuperCar* as a argument, but it doesn't find it because of different type of arguments( *Car* vs *SuperCar*)

```
public sellCarTest(){
    SuperCar superCar = new SuperCar();
    CarDealer carDealer = new CarDealer();
    Class dealer = CarDealer.class;
    Class[] args = Class[1];
    args[0] = superCar.getClass();
    Method m = dealer.getDeclaredMethod("sellCar", args);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(carDealer, superCar);
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually I've seen piece of code pasted in accepted answer, but it still didn't gave me correct answer.

I've found my answer here [Testing private method using power mock which return list of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104985/testing-private-method-using-power-mock-which-return-list-of-integers)

Comment: Use `args[0] = Car.class;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the java source code of `Class` class, you can see the way it compares the arguments given for getting a method

```
private static boolean arrayContentsEq(Object[] a1, Object[] a2) {
    if (a1 == null) {
        return a2 == null || a2.length == 0;
    }

    if (a2 == null) {
        return a1.length == 0;
    }

    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can quickly check that

```
    Object X = P.class;
    Object Y = Q.class;// Q implements P
    System.out.println(X == Y);
```

will always print  `false`. So you will not find any method with such arguments

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough, just cast SuperCar to Car:

```
public sellCarTest(){
    **Car** superCar = new SuperCar();
    CarDealer carDealer = new CarDealer();
    // ... rest of the method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class.get*Method() looks for methods with parameters of exactly the types you specify. It doesn't respect subtype relationships between the types you specify and the types of the formal parameters of the method; nor does it respect primitive/wrapper relationships, or primitive widening.

You might be able to get the behavior you need by using java.beans.Statement or java.beans.Expression.